# Efficient way to selectively unpower USB ports

Tags: power-supply, usb

(Edited and expanded from original question for clarity)

USB interfaces as a means of controlling external hardware from a desktop or laptop computer are ubiquitous; many thousands of hardware models are available, ranging in price from 10<sup>-1</sup> to 10<sup>6</sup> USD. It is reasonable to require that the +5V DC voltage line be able to be switched off from the host computer, but this is by no means guaranteed across every mainstream PC/laptop running every widespread OS.

I am looking to have a true cross-platform solution to be able to selectively power USB ports down and up from software, for totally arbitrary lengths of time. This is not because I am prototyping or breadboarding, and nor is this my first foray into electronics making an LED blink on and off; I require a long-term reliable solution.

I am looking for an efficient solution which minimizes:

- Cost
- Implementation time
- Other general hassles, such as volume or amount of trailing wires

Based upon comments, I have thusfar ranked my options as follows:

**Option 1**

Buy a dedicated USB splitter, with fully cross-platform proprietary software, such as the [Yepkit YKUSH hub](https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush):

[image: YKUSH]

- $42
- Negligble software compilation time + some time to "box up"
- Compact and neat

**Option 2**

Buy a [programmable USB hub](https://acroname.com/store/s77-usbhub-2x4?sku=S77-USBHUB-2X4):

[image: programmable hub]

- $300
- Small amount of time to implement command-line software control
- Professionally boxed

At the moment, I would be tempted to get a 4-way USB hub, splice its power lines through a separate arduino-controlled relay (as I have an arduino that need never be unpowered).

**Option 3**

Buy a fairly off-the shelf hub compatible with [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/blob/master/README.md). Then either run Linux or program a way to make it work in Windows. A VM would also be a headache, because programs in Windows will have trouble interfacing with Linux programs inside the VM.

- ~[$20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00552PMN8)
- Long time to implement cross-platform software
- Professional USB hub

**Option 4**

Buy a USB hub and a Normally Closed 5V relay, controlled by *e.g.* an arduino to cut power to the USB hub as required:

[image: arduino relay]

- ~$25
- Long time to solder and tidy connections + short time to implement switching in arduino code
- Fairy ugly due to splicing wires

(Surprisingly not suggested in responses given that this is an Electrical Engineering site)

Comment: Is this an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: @Jeroen3 In what sense?

Comment: In what sense? In the sense of why do you need to turn VBUS off. Is it for repeated test to determine device reliability, or for test of software connectivity, or just to restart some badly designed remote debugger?

Comment: @Ale..chenski: no, it's not. It is perfectly understandable desire to be able to have software switching for something that can be done manually by unplugging and replugging USB cable. It's a shame that many hardware manufacturers decided to not implement that part of USB spec, and software vendors like Microsoft make it impossible to use even if hardware supports it.

Comment: @mvp Exactly. If I could accept that comment as an answer, I would.

Comment: @mvp, USB was envisioned as a cheap plug-n-play service. Individual port power control is optional per specifications, most systems use "ganged power" going for cheapest option, since individual hi-side switches cost serious money, frequently doubling the cost of USB hubs for example. Something like 95% of systems don't have the power control. And for all normal use cases you don't need to disconnect  (re-plug) normal USB devices if they conform to USB specifications and carry real USB-IF certification logo. So your complaint is unfounded.

Comment: I doubt very much that you can find "option3" for $20. In most cases hubs have different population options on same PCB, and in most cases the hi-side switches are DNP and replaced with dumb polyfuses. And you will never know until you open the enclosure and inspect the board. I bet the list shown in uhubctl is impossible to buy anywhere, half is EOL already, and the other half will have polyfuses.

Comment: @Ale..chenski This hub is $15 and is listed as compatible with uhubctl: https://www.amazon.com/Rosewill-Anti-Dust-Rubber-SuperSpeed-Windows/dp/B00552PMN8
mvp is **absolutely** right that e.g. a laptop costing $1500 should have switchable 5V lines on its USB ports. If it's expensive to do so, they are designed poorly.

Comment: Rosewill $15 hub - good luck, as I explained, there might be mass production caveats with de-populated parts.

Comment: *"It is reasonable to require that the +5V DC voltage line be able to be switched off from the host computer"* (at user's will I guess) - unfortunately, 40+ USB architects and senior engineers (contributors to USB 2.0 specifications) didn't find this requirement reasonable, and 200+ authors of USB 3.x specifications agree with this as well.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Ah yes, appeal to authority... 200 cardinals judged that the Earth is flat, so Giordano Bruno was burned at the stake. 200 IoT developers found it reasonable that a lightbulb has to receive firmware updates for 1 hour, so here we are...

Comment: You are not a Giordano, and you still fail to explain why you (or some other regular user) would need that extra manual control over port power, other than expressing a "desire" to have this option. Especially if it is not supported by hardware in 99% of USB equipment.

Comment: @ValentinAslanyan So far you haven't given any reason for disconnecting power to USB devices. "understandable desire" and "reasonable to require" are not reasons, they are opinions. To say that "authorities" made arbitrary unfounded decision while your opinion has all the merits is rather arrogant. Unless you can provide any _real_ reason to supplement your case this discussion will lead nowhere.

Comment: And yes, for many very practical applications as land survey, tax appraisal, and architecture/fllorplanning the flat Earth model is still predominant. If Giordano Bruno failed to explain that any differentiable manifold is locally flat, it might be his problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, PPPS (per port power switching) appear to be required by USB 3.2, as part of USB PD. So, not all USB designers agree with you, @Ale...chenski.

Comment: @Maple As it happens (not that it has any bearing on the question whatsoever) I have a set of Renishaw optical encoders (total monetary cost of order 10000 USD) which must be selectively unpowered. The manufacturers themselves said that this functionality was not originally designed, but sought after by many users, and said that cutting power was the only real option.

Why would other users want this? My option 1 - a custom made for-profit board to solve this problem certainly has some suggestions, *e.g.* extend HDD life.

Please tell me more about how the Earth is flat, though...

Comment: "optical encoders ... which must be selectively unpowered", "... cutting power was the only real option". These do not sound like _reasons_ still. More like workarounds for badly designed devices. My dishwasher periodically locks up for no apparent reason and the only way to revive it is to cut the power at the breaker box. But if you tell me that the reason to have manual breaker control is because "dishwashers must be selectively unpowered" I'd concur that the Earth is indeed flat.

Comment: @Maple I don't understand your point. Yes, in that sense the encoders are poorly designed. I need to unpower them. Should I reverse engineer these expensive, high precision devices, or buy a $42 switchable hub?

Comment: My point was that there is no reason whatsoever for hub designers to introduce features only because they could be used to deal with faulty devices. Note, that I was only answering your claim that these features should have been included in hubs. Your actual question is a sound electrical design problem, and you already identified several workable solutions and had some useful answers, neither of which required modifications of your expensive encoders.

Comment: What solution did you choose? Did you test the different options you mentioned?

Comment: @user276648 I chose option 1 and 3D-printed the case from the appropriate files provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for - as for folks wondering about why you'd need to power cycle a USB device: software license dongles come to mind. Or in my case, are literally the thing. They store a machine identifier that persists for as long as there is power running, so even if you have multiple computers in your house and you own "USB Network Gate" to proxy your USB devices over the network, you _still_ need a way to power cycle the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you can simulate disconnect event using utility [`devcon`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) provided by Microsoft. Use it as outlined in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/502055/171440). However, it doesn't necessarily mean that power will be turned off.

On other platforms (Linux, Mac) you can use my utility [**uhubctl**](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl). It will work and actually turn power off per each port selectively for any USB hub that supports per port power control (check compatibility list for tested devices). Good news is that uhubctl supports USB 3 and many USB 3 hubs properly support per port power control.

Comment: It's not only the hub chip that needs support, the control pins must actually connect to FETs/switches on the board

Comment: Certainly. This is why uhubctl has supported devices list.

Comment: Uhubctl works like a champ in the project I'm working on, a very useful tool.

Comment: This is not a "simulation" of port disconnect. Port disconnect is a logical state of any USB port, per USB specifications. Disabling a USB port turns it into non-transmitting port, and the corresponding software instance gets removed. Enabling the port can be done only by issuing a USB port reset, and following with new, fresh enumeration. This function can be performed regardless of whether the port has controllable VBUS power or not. The OP failed to explain  why he needs to toggle VBUS power (which is the simplest external way to disable and force re-enumeration of  a USB port).

Comment: @Ale..chenski: read this list of examples why people needed this functionality: https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/blob/master/README.md#notable-projects-using-uhubctl

Comment: In my experience `devcon` does not actually power things off. Do you know/think this is the software's fault, or could it be dependent on the hardware?

Comment: @user276648: It is hard to tell. For this to work, there are 2 basic requirements: USB hub must actually support per port power switching, and winusb.sys should be actually sending power off event to involved device. On Linux or Mac, this works as long as hardware supports it, see more at my project page [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl).

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible in some cases, but it depends on the hardware you're running.

Some USB chipsets allow "per-port power control" (the name of this feature seems to change from one manufacturer to another).  Your mileage may vary because this feature appears to be an optional part of the USB3 spec.

There is an unofficial and probably incomplete list of chips that support this feature here: https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/blob/master/README.md

Uhubctl is a Linux based program that lets you turn on and off USB ports on compatible chipsets.  Works for individual ports on PCIe-to-USB adaptor cards too.  It can be run from the commandline or a shell script and you just nominate which port you want to turn on or off.

If your hardware contains one of the supported chips (and the manufacturer chose to implement it on your motherboard / PCIe card) then that is one option that works for me natively under Linux.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly an option. While I am typing this reply on Linux, I need a Windows solution. I would have to buy one of the listed (and, simultaneously still stocked) hubs, then adapt the C code to Winapi, or preferrably to python... so will take quite some time.

Comment: Do you have the option to run a Windows virtual machine on top of a Linux host PC?  If so then the Linux software side takes care of itself and all you need do from the Windows side is send a TCP packet to the host machine (over the local LAN) to tell the host to powercycle the port(s).  But yes, finding hardware that works might be tricky.  I had to do it the hard way and build one of these chips into my project!

Comment: Are you suggesting running a VM just to be able to unpower USB ports? :) That is in no way an efficient solution.

Comment: From the C code in the github, it looks like only the libusb.h is needed (hopefully this is OS-independent), from which one needs to call something like libusb_control_transfer(devh, LIBUSB_REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS | LIBUSB_RECIPIENT_OTHER, request, USB_PORT_FEAT_POWER, port, NULL, 0, USB_CTRL_GET_TIMEOUT);. This should be doable with python as well.

Comment: @ValentinAslanyan, I know using a VM isn't ideal, but it might be a quick win depending on the OP's requirements.  Porting the C code would be better obviously, if it can be made reliable.  If that is feasible then it's worth contacting the authors of uhubctl, perhaps they can incorporate the changes to the main branch of the software.

Comment: Yes, `uhubctl` only needs `libusb` to compile and work, and it does compile on Windows. But on Windows, `libusb` is using `winusb.sys`, which doesn't support required USB control message directly to the hub. More details in [uhubctl docs](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl#compiling)

Comment: Many hub chips have output pins to control power switches but that doesn't mean the board has those switches.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I did mention that in the last paragraph.  Often the feature is not implemented on the PCB to save costs (mosfets etc).  The cheapo PCIe boards I got from ebay didn't have the necessary external components, but it did use the hub chip that I was interested in, so I just soldered wires onto the 2 power control pins and cobbled together a working proof of concept.

Answer (score 2):

First, not all desktop PC have individual port power control, actually very few have it. You will have a better luck with external hubs, although it will be also a challenge.

Second, USB port power, connect, reset, enable etc. port function are integrated steps of USB protocol, and are implemented at kernel level. Enabling port power is the first standard function for any root (or normal) hub port, and turning it off is not in the standard USB protocol. Therefore you would need the usb driver source code to implement new custom calls and functions. If this is theoretically available for Linux/Android, it is highly problematic under Windows.

However, if this is for testing of individual basic USB functions under manual control and no "normal" USB class functionality is needed/required, there is a stand-alone software package called  ["USB3CV" - command verifier](http://www.usb.org/developers/tools/), available from USB.ORG, which replaces the standard Windows USB stack and allows to execute individual port commands via graphic interface. This again assumes that the hardware (USB hub) has individual port power controllers, which is hard to get in first place.

If you need a normal USB stack functionality but want to exercise systematic power-off (VBUS off/disconnect) of connected USB devices, your best option is to get a hub with individual port power control, and hack the control wires to your Arduino controller.

Again, it all depends what is the purpose of your exercise, there might be some caveats in the disconnect process.

ADDITION: In classic USB environment with Type-A ports the individual port power switching is OPTIONAL and should't be generally expected from on-the-shelf products. However, for all devices with Type-C downstream connectors the individual port power control is MANDATORY by USB 3.2 specifications. Therefore, Type-C is the way to go (into future).

Comment: +1 nice tip about the USB3CV tools.